# math.floor(21000*0.7) returns 14699 but math.floor(14700.0) returns 14700

Tags: math, lua, floor

## Problem

as title mentioned, when use `math.floor()` on `21000*0.7` and `14700.0` the returned value is different.

`math.floor(21000*0.7)` returns `14699`, but `math.floor(14700.0)` returns `14700`.

## Lua versions

5.3.x and 5.4.x

Comment: This is just a classic floating point math error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Reason

The behavior you're getting is because of floating point inaccuracies. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples) question for more details, but in a nutshell, the reason is similar to why we can't represent `1 / 3` (0.33 repeating) with a finite amount of digits in decimal.

You can test it yourself! Use formatting to get a more precise string representation, and print it:

```lua
print(("%.14f"):format(21000*0.7))
```

Prints `14699.99999999999818`!

Lua `tostring` doesn't have this precision. Some dialects change that because like in your case, it can be confusing. This is also why `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` evaluates to `false`, but printing both expressions individually prints `0.3`.

## Solution

The solution is to do it this way: `21000 * 7 / 10`, assuming that 21000 will be replaced by a variable. If the entire fraction will be unknown, and if 21000 will be replaced by an integer, then you can try doing this: `21000 * 0.7 + 0.1` (as the argument of `floor`)